# Out of memory error while generating code coverage report using gcov

Tags: android-ndk, code-coverage, native-code, gcov

I am trying to run code coverage for a sample project provided by googleTest by following the instuctions given in ReadMe file present here https://github.com/sfuku7/googletest_android_ndk-build.

When i run this command
lcov --gcov-tool /path/to/ndk/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android-gcov --capture --directory obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/sample_code_test_code_coverage --output-file coverage.info
I get error :
Processing SampleCode.gcda
Out of memory!

I have tried with other tool chains as well instead of x86-4.6. Gives the same issue.

Comment: Make sure that your compiled code compiler and gcov tool compiler are same version and same tool

Comment: @vinay : can u please tell me how to check the same? I am new to this and have been following the instruactions in read me file blindly.

Comment: I have tried with all tool chains. I am using same ndk to build the code. Does that mean that compiled code compiler and gcov tool compiler have same version?